# ¿Cómo eliminar registros repetidos según ID, de consulta en SqlServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesitó quitar los registros con ID repetidos de la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT A.Id,A.AppointmentReason, A.AppointmentDate, A.DateCreate, A.StartHour, A.EndHour, B.Industry
        FROM  dbo.ScheduledVirtualAppointments AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN
              dbo.IndustryTemp AS B ON A.NumberId = B.NumberId 
              WHERE Industry  IS NOT NULL
              GROUP BY A.Id,  A.AppointmentReason, A.AppointmentDate, A.DateCreate, A.StartHour, A.EndHour, B.Industry
```

Filas retornadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y quedarte con cuál registro?, las industrias son diferentes

Comment: No importa con cual industria quede el registro...

Comment: Si no importa con cual te quedas, para que las traes? no las traigas, quitalas de todos lados y listo.. no mas registros duplicados...

Comment: Capaz querias usar un where exists?

Comment: gbianchi , sii debe mostrar  alguna .... como referencia

Comment: Como referencia de? Si uno incluye algo en la proyección (en el resultado de la consulta), es porque tiene una relación con el resto de datos en el registro. "No importa" no es algo expresable en SQL

Comment: como referencia, ya tienes que devuelve un registro. Si quitas eso, ya tenes tu solucion. Y si viene algo, es que existe algo! no se a que te referis como referencia.. no existe eso como dice Alfabravo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurre la siguiente solución, sin embargo, esto se puede optimizar de mil formas porque no es la más óptima:

1. Haga uso del `SELECT INTO`

```sql
SELECT A.Id,A.AppointmentReason, A.AppointmentDate, A.DateCreate, 
       A.StartHour, A.EndHour, B.Industry
INTO my_table
FROM  dbo.ScheduledVirtualAppointments AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.IndustryTemp AS B ON A.NumberId = B.NumberId 
WHERE Industry IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY A.Id,  A.AppointmentReason, A.AppointmentDate, A.DateCreate, 
         A.StartHour, A.EndHour, B.Industry
```

> Le quedará la consulta que tiene actualmente, pero lo tendrá en una tabla. Al menos para esta solución eso será de utilidad.

2. Declare variables

```sql
declare @contador int = 1 
declare @limite int = (select max(Id) from my_table)
declare @tablita table(Id int, AppointmentReason varchar(200), AppointmentDate date, 
DateCreate date, StartHour int, EndHour int, Industry varchar(200))
```

> He supuesto el tipo de dato que tienen sus columnas.

3. Haga uso del bucle `WHILE`

```sql
while @contador <= @limite begin 

 declare @id int = null 
 declare @AppointmentReason varchar(200) = null
 declare @AppointmentDate date = null
 declare @DateCreate date = null
 declare @StartHour int = null
 declare @EndHour int = null
 declare @Industry varchar(200) = null

 if exists(select 1 from my_table where id = @contador) begin 
  select top 1 @id = Id, @AppointmentReason = AppointmentReason , 
  @AppointmentDate = AppointmentDate , @DateCreate = DateCreate , @StartHour = StartHour , 
  @EndHour = EndHour ,   @Industry = Industry 
  from my_table
  where id = @contador
 
  insert into @tablita values (@id, @AppointmentReason , @AppointmentDate , @DateCreate , 
  @StartHour ,@EndHour,@Industry   )
 end 

set @contador = @contador + 1

end
```

4. Compruebe los resultados

```sql
select * 
from @tablita
```

> [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0d7354b25425f25c16aa1449b0ffe77f) donde lo ejecuté.

---

#### EDIT:

Otra manera que encontré es usando CTE's.

```sql
;with Tablota as ( 

SELECT A.Id,A.AppointmentReason, A.AppointmentDate, A.DateCreate, 
       A.StartHour, A.EndHour, B.Industry
FROM  dbo.ScheduledVirtualAppointments AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.IndustryTemp AS B ON A.NumberId = B.NumberId 
WHERE Industry IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY A.Id,  A.AppointmentReason, A.AppointmentDate, A.DateCreate, 
         A.StartHour, A.EndHour, B.Industry  
)

select *
from Tablota externo 
where externo.Industry = (select top 1 Industry 
                        from Tablota interno 
                        where Id = externo.Id)
```

Answer (score 3):

Como te mencionaron en los comentarios, el problema es que estás trayendo información que no debes. Si corriges el problema desde el origen, puedes tener una solución más eficiente.

Por otro lado, la forma más sencilla que tienes para solucionar el problema es aprovechar que ya estás agrupando y usar una función de agregado.

```
SELECT  SVA.Id,
        SVA.AppointmentReason, 
        SVA.AppointmentDate, 
        SVA.DateCreate, 
        SVA.StartHour, 
        SVA.EndHour, 
        MAX( IT.Industry) AS Industry
FROM  dbo.ScheduledVirtualAppointments AS SVA 
INNER JOIN dbo.IndustryTemp            AS IT  ON SVAA.NumberId = IT.NumberId 
WHERE IT.Industry IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY SVA.Id,  
         SVA.AppointmentReason, 
         SVA.AppointmentDate, 
         SVA.DateCreate, 
         SVA.StartHour, 
         SVA.EndHour;
```

Nota como cambié los alias de las tablas para que tengan una relación lógica con la tabla y no con el orden en el que aparecen dentro del código. También cambié el tipo de JOIN ya que no tiene sentido usar un LEFT JOIN si no quieres que la columna regrese nulos. Otro detalle importante es el formato, tienes que escribir tu código para que sea fácilmente legible.

Otra opción que tienes, es la de cambiar el JOIN por algo que regrese solo una fila de la segunda tabla por cada fila de la primera. Dejo 2 ejemplos:

```
-- Usando CROSS APPLY para que busque la primer fila que coincida
SELECT  SVA.Id,
        SVA.AppointmentReason, 
        SVA.AppointmentDate, 
        SVA.DateCreate, 
        SVA.StartHour, 
        SVA.EndHour, 
        I.Industry
FROM  dbo.ScheduledVirtualAppointments AS SVA 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 
                    IT.Industry 
             FROM   dbo.IndustryTemp AS IT  
             WHERE  SVAA.NumberId = IT.NumberId 
             AND    IT.Industry IS NOT NULL) I;

-- Usando un CTE para asignar números a las filas y regresar las que tengan el número 1
-- El CTE se puede cambiar por una subconsulta en el JOIN
WITH cteIndustry AS(
    SELECT IT.Industry,
           IT.NumberId,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY IT.NumberId ORDER BY IT.NumberId ) AS rn
    FROM   dbo.IndustryTemp AS IT  
    WHERE  IT.Industry IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT  SVA.Id,
        SVA.AppointmentReason, 
        SVA.AppointmentDate, 
        SVA.DateCreate, 
        SVA.StartHour, 
        SVA.EndHour, 
        I.Industry
FROM  dbo.ScheduledVirtualAppointments AS SVA 
JOIN  cteIndustry                      AS I   ON SVAA.NumberId = I.NumberId
WHERE I.rn = 1;
```

Es importante señalar, que estas opciones no garanticen que siempre se regrese la misma fila. Se regresará la primera disponible y eso puede variar por muchas causas. Para mantener resultados constantes es necesario agregar o corregir el `ORDER BY` para que ordene de la manera adecuada.